# How to use Golang to get my wifi ip address?

Tags: go, ip, ip-address

```
func getLocalIP() ([]string, error) {
    addrs, err := net.InterfaceAddrs()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    IPs := make([]string, 0)
    for _, a := range addrs {
        if ipNet, ok := a.(*net.IPNet); ok && !ipNet.IP.IsLoopback() {
            if ipNet.IP.To4() != nil {
                IPs = append(IPs, ipNet.IP.To4().String())
            }
        }
    }
    return IPs, nil
}
func TestGetLocalIP() {
    addrs, _ := getLocalIP()
    for _, a := range addrs {
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}
```

I used this,but it give me a list of ip address.

I just want to get my wifi local address,how to do that?

Comment: Impossible in a cross-platform way using only the `net` package—the level of abstraction it implements is oblivious to the types of networking hardware used to carry the IP packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know at least one of two pieces of information going in:

1. the name of the correct interface (typically `en0` on a Mac, e.g., but YMMV)
2. the address for your wireless network, including the length of the mask - something like 192.168.0.0/16 or 192.168.0.0/24 is pretty common, but you'll have to figure this out ahead of time.

#### If you only know the interface name:

```go
ifs, _ := net.Interfaces()
for _, ifi := range ifs {
  if ifi.Name == "en0" { // Or whatever other filter you want
    addrs, _ := ifi.Addresses()
    for _, a := range addrs {
      // Filter to get the one you want, typically unicast IP4
    }
  }
}
```

Still simpler:

```go
if, _ := net.InterfaceByName("en0")
addrs, _ := if.Addresses()
for _, a := range addrs {
  // As before, filter for the address you want
}
```

#### If you know the network address for your wireless network

```go
// Loop over interfaces, get addrs, then loop over addresses and get IPs for those that have them
if ip.Mask(net.CIDRMask(16, 32)) == myNetworkAddress {
  // The interface you got this IP from is probably your wifi interface
}
```

#### Which method to choose

Depending on the interface having a specific name is generally not going to be portable.  So while my assumption was that you were just trying to get this working on your own workstation, if this is for something which needs to run across multiple hosts, you may need to start off at least with matching against the correct network address.  There are other tricks as well - if you know e.g. that you are going to be running in a server farm in which every host has a NIC from manufacturer XXX, you can look up the MAC address and see if it comes from that manufacturer - you can try this out [here](https://maclookup.app/).  You can use other filters as well, but those are going to be pretty specific to your individual use case.

Comment: thanks for your help. I use 
ifs, _ := net.Interfaces()
for _, ifi := range ifs {
  if ifi.Name == "WLAN" { // Or whatever other filter you want
    addrs, _ := ifi.Addrs()
    for _, a := range addrs {
    
    }
  }
}
and i got my ip address.

Comment: This should be made clear in the answer that the interface names are not in any way suitable for making such decisions. This might work for a kludge solution in a fully controlled environment but not for production code which is supposed to work in environments not controlled by the programmer.

Comment: @kostix while your point is generally valid (and I've added a kludgy paragraph to that effect), it is not universally so.  E.g. NICs (particularly vNICs) might be assigned names deterministically to an extent that you could compute the name before looking up the address.  Again - I think the burden of figuring out the appropriateness of the approach is on the reader.

Comment: I was thinking of something different. Like, you cannot sensibly ship what is called a "shrink-wrapped" software package and require the end user to somehow mess with the settings of their OS to meet the program's demands ;-)